# focus() method does not work in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to focus on an anchor in jquery

i am using these codes:

```
$(textBox).parent().next().find('a').first().focus();
```

or

```
$(textBox).parent().next().find('a')[0].focus();
```

but these codes does not work

while

```
   $(textBox).parent().next().find('a').first()
```

returns:

```
<a role="menuitem" class=""><strong>101</strong>0320117585</a>
```

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3eHQu/

Comment: Because your anchors have a `href`. But using a `tabindex` as proposed by @Lucas M. Oliveira is even better I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your anchor needs to have a `href` attribute (at least in Chrome).
If you don't need a special `href` you can use `href="javascript:void(0);"`

Answer (score 1):

Two things you should a ID on that anchor and also a tab-index, and as prefer a negative value, and it will not in IE even the 8:

```
<a href="someWhere" id="someName" tabindex=-1>Click Me!<a/>
```